# How to fix "error: symbol `grub_disk_get_size' not found."?

Tags: partition, grub2

My computer was running a dual boot with Arch and Manjaro on their own partitions. I decided I wanted to exchange Manjaro for Debian, so I flashed the USB and deleted the Manjaro partition. Apparently that's the one Grub wants to boot from though, so I get shifted into `grub rescue>` mode.

I want to at least boot into Arch, and ideally get a grub menu where I can boot from the USB containing the Debian installer.

The problem is when I run `insmod normal`, I get the error in the title.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the order boot in the BIOS options. I've the same problem with this message at start, and this was the problem.